# function returns empty object before return statement

Tags: javascript

This function is confusing me, it runs if I remove the return giving an empty object. And with the return statement there it ignores it and does the same thing.
Not sure what's going on here, there is clearly no other return statement.

```
var score = function(string){
    var sum = 0;
    if(string.length > 0){
        string = string.toLowerCase();
        var array = string.split('');
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(var letter in letters){
                if(array[i] === letter) {
                    sum += letters[array[i]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
};
```

this is the letters array not that it's relevant

```
var letters = {
    a : 1, e : 1, i : 1, o : 1, u : 1, l : 1, n : 1, r : 1, s : 1, t : 1, d : 2, g : 2, b : 3, c : 3, m : 3, p : 3, f : 4, h : 4, v : 4, w : 4, y : 4, k : 5, j : 8, x : 8, q : 10, z : 10
}
```

using jasmine to test. for example

```
it('scores an empty word as zero',function() { expect(new score('')).toEqual(0); });
```

Comment: Your code is working for me.  How are you calling the function score?  For me, `score('hello')` returns 8.

Comment: How do you invoke it? How do you check the result it returns? Btw, you don't need the nested loop.

Comment: using jasmine to test. for example
it('scores an empty word as zero',function() {
    expect(new score('')).toEqual(0);
  });

Comment: Why do you use `new` here? What is the technical reason for that?

Comment: There is no need to loop over `letters`, since letters is an object just use an if statement to make sure the property exists then do the addition: `if(letters[array[i]]) sum+=letters[array[i]]`

Comment: Ahh removing new fixed it actually. I was originally trying to do some variation with the this keyword so thought new would be helpful. Not sure why removing new made it work though?

Comment: `new` makes the function act as a constructor, so it returns an instance, [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: wasn't I using a return statement in the function? And thank you for the if statement idea, that's much less complex

Comment: @PatrickEvans is right, except that it ignores the value you return if it's a primitive. It only lets you return objects when you use `new`.

Comment: @ZackLucky "Not sure why removing new made it work though?" --- when you write code, be prepared to justify use of every character in your code. Now tell us - *why* did you put `new` there? If you cannot explain the purpose of every character in *your code* - stop there and spend some time learning before you continue.

Comment: @zerkms I originally put it there because I was going to make use of a constructor and the this keyword in a separate function. After I changed my plan of attack without also making sure to remove the new it caused these issues. And since I didn't know that using new forces the constructor to return an object I didn't see the issue. That little factoid will be very helpful in the future I think.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as is, with only a simple undefined check.  'testz' should alert 14, no?

```
var letters = {
    a : 1, e : 1, i : 1, o : 1, u : 1, l : 1, n : 1, r : 1, s : 1, t : 1, d : 2, g : 2, b : 3, c : 3, m : 3, p : 3, f : 4, h : 4, v : 4, w : 4, y : 4, k : 5, j : 8, x : 8, q : 10, z : 10
};

var score = function(string){
    var sum = 0;
    if(typeof string !== 'undefined' && string.length > 0){
        string = string.toLowerCase();
        var array = string.split('');
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(var letter in letters){
                if(array[i] === letter) {
                    sum += letters[array[i]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
};


alert(score('testz'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c7eq8g46/